# A prime divisor $p$ of Fermat number $F_n$ is a Wieferich prime if and only if $p^2$ divides $F_n$

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $F_n=2^{{2^n}}+1$, $n\geq 1$  ( Fermat numbers) and $p>2$ a prime number sucht that $p|F_n$

I want to show if true that :

$p$ is  Wieferich prime number $\Longleftrightarrow $ $p^2|F_n$

the sense $\Longleftarrow$

If $p>2$ is a prime number and divides $F_n$, then $p=1+k2^{n+1}$ for some $k\in \mathbb N$. If we assume that $p^2$ divides $F_n$, then $2^{2^n}\equiv -1 \mod p^2$, and with this integer $k$ ($k=\frac{p-1}{2^{n+1}}$), we have $2^{k2^{n+1}}=(2^{2^n})^{2k}\equiv 1 \mod p^2$. Thus, $2^{p-1}\equiv 1 \mod p^2$, which implies that $p^2$ divides $2^{p-1}-1$. thus $p$ is  Wieferich prime number .

If the sense $\Longrightarrow$ is true, can you give me help

**Addition**

My research goal is to try to prove;
If prime $p>3,\quad  p|F_n$ then  $p^2\not| F_n$

The difficulty is that I have no way to prove this conjecture and it's also difficult to provide a counterexample because if $p| F_n$ and $p^2| F_n$, as above, then p is a Wieferich prime, but only two numbers of this type are known at the moment.

Comment: This result (the first equivalence you state) is in the book by Krizek, Luca, Somer, *17 Lectures on Fermat numbers*, Theorem 6.22. Apparently it appears earlier in the work of several authors.

Comment: Can I know why the topic is closed? I am not very familiar with MO's policy, does the problem have to be popular to remain open?

Comment: There is a similar problem for Mrsenne numbers. https://mathoverflow.net/users/12481/joro

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the $\Longrightarrow$ sense, note we have, for some positive integer $m$, that

$$p \mid 2^{2^n} + 1 \;\;\to\;\; p \mid 2^{2^{n+1}} - 1 \;\;\to\;\; mp + 1 = 2^{2^{n+1}} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

From your definition of

$$p = 1 + k2^{n+1} \;\;\to\;\; p - 1 = k2^{n+1} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

we then get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
2^{p-1} & = (2^{2^{n+1}})^k \\
& = (mp + 1)^k \\
& = (mp)^{k} + k(mp)^{k-1} + \ldots + \frac{k(k-1)}{2}(mp)^2 + k(mp) + 1
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Thus,
$$2^{p-1} - 1 \equiv k(mp) \pmod{p^2} \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Using the definition of [Wieferich prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wieferich_prime), we then have

$$p^2 \mid 2^{p-1} - 1 \;\;\to\;\; p \mid km \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

Since \eqref{eq2A} shows $p \nmid k$, then $p \mid m$. Thus, \eqref{eq1A} gives that

$$p^2 \mid 2^{2^{n+1}} - 1 = (2^{2^n} + 1)(2^{2^n} - 1) \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

Since $p \mid 2^{2^n} + 1$ and $\gcd(2^{2^n} + 1, 2^{2^n} - 1) = 1$, we get

$$p^2 \mid 2^{2^n} + 1 \;\;\to\;\; p^2 \mid F_n \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

---

Alternatively, using the first $2$ parts of \eqref{eq1A} and \eqref{eq2A},  plus that $p \nmid k$, then the [Lifting-the-exponent lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifting-the-exponent_lemma) gives that

$$\nu_p(2^{p-1}-1) = \nu_p\left((2^{2^{n+1}})^k-1\right) = \nu_p(2^{2^{n+1}}-1) + \nu_p(k) = \nu_p(2^{2^{n+1}}-1) \tag{8}\label{eq8A}$$

Then use the first part of \eqref{eq5A} and continue from \eqref{eq6A} to get to the same conclusion.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's really clear and detailed

Answer (score 2):

This also follows from a general identity

https://arxiv.org/pdf/2112.04173.pdf

that if $p$ is a odd prime, $p \not| a, p|(a^n + 1)$, then

$\nu_p(a^n + 1)=\nu_p(n)+\nu_p(a^{p-1}-1)$ so that

$\nu_p(F_n)=\nu_p(a^{p-1}-1)$

which gives a bit more.

This is stronger than the Lifting the exponent lemma which require knowing $p|(a+1)$ first, that's why the previous answer need step (1) & (2).